# Suspicious voting activity occurring when assisting with the Apple tag burnination

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, burninate-system

I haven't been very active with the Apple burnination, but on a whim, I spent a day in the CV queue [closing apple tag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass?tab=activity&sort=reviews). One day, about 40 close votes. This was on May 3rd.

On May 4th, I received a downvote for one of my few low-impact questions. I shrugged it off.
On May 7th, I received an additional downvote, for one of my two remaining low-impact questions. On a whole, these three questions account for approximately 600 views in total, and have been on the site for the better part of three years with no real activity, positive or negative, [and these are the first downvotes I have ever received on my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958086/compass?tab=reputation).

Upon inquiring with other people active in the burnination about this, I was told that a few people had noticed it on themselves, but had not realized it was widespread.

Out of the boredom of somehow being up at 3 in the morning, I went through the user profiles of everyone I could find who had participated in the close vote queue, and tracked any downvotes they received during the period of May 4th through May 7th by time.

[image: Exhibit A]

This list isn't complete, as I know a few more people were affected, and I can't access docs at the moment.

However, the amount of question downvotes clustering together minutes apart appears to be too large to be a coincidence. I also found no "unique" close vote that involved all of us, so I assume it may not be targeted at any one individual question being closed, but against the [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) burnination entirely.

I'm not particularly concerned about rep, more concerned about the fact that helping clean up some tags has made some people the target of downvoting for nothing more than collaborating to clean up unsuitable questions.

Comment: *"I also found no "unique" close vote that involved all of us"* But you may can find questions of the same author which you all together voted to close. But finding that might be hard and error-prone.

Comment: It should be noted that the downvotes only occurred on questions, never answers (no rep loss for the voter) and they were never enough to trigger the serial downvote reversal script

Comment: I am not a vigilante, I am a simple in-bread cat.

Comment: @Machavity "and they were never enough to trigger the serial downvote reversal script" Since it were single DVs per day, it won't trigger here. That script only triggers for serial votings in a very short period of time (afair).

Comment: @Tom I got 2 back to back. I think the minimum is 3

Comment: It must be as I too got 2 back to back as did Bhargav Rao. Those kind of votes do feel iffy.Especially when the questions don't get much activity if at all any.

Comment: Yes might be true. The actual behaviour of that reversal script is quite a secret to aviod gaming it, but I remember reading something about 2 DV in a row without that script kicking in.

Comment: This is why people stop using the hammer, closing even as helpful as duplicate is not appreciate, but hey staying at the front-line you need to be ready to take some casualties.

Comment: "*Out of the boredom of somehow being up at 3AM in the morning*" I know that feeling.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the apple tag, as I've noticed something similar after closing a question once.

Comment: @IanS *closing a question once* - exactly - the thing here is that it's happening frequently

Comment: feature request: don't show links (only the names) for the close voters' pages for users with less than X rep?

Comment: @CássioRenan I don't think that's the correct solution. We should be held accountable when we close something. People, even new people, should know who is involved in a closed ticket. And this is likely the work of someone who is well-versed in Stack Overflow. I doubt a new user is going to go Hulk and downvote everyone who terminated his first question.

Comment: I've since answered a question to compensate for the huge amount of reputation that I lost due to these unjustified down votes. If you will excuse me now, I have a tag to burn ...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This looks like someone is upset about their question or questions being closed, and is retaliating by downvoting the close voters. We've seen this before, but moderators don't have the best tools for tracking this down.

The evidence has been presented to Stack Exchange employees, and they are reviewing it. It may take a little while for them to process this, given the complexity of the situation.

Comment: This, of course, will be remedied once Stackoverflow becomes self-aware ;)

Comment: Is anything to come of this Brad?

Comment: @BradLarson I faced the same problem after I got the hammer at [tag:jasper-reports]. I flagged my problem, but in my case it was a "smart" downvoting chain - 2 downvotes at first day and another one at second day. I'm not sure that it is a last case