# Can we add another point to the burnination process in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

*[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)*

As shown in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355967/3956566) to a [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request), *[Should we burninate the [entry] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/should-we-burninate-the-entry-tag)*, there's been a community wiki made for all replacement tag suggestions.

This would assist in resolving many issue around the burnination process. Close voting and downvoting questions where there's [controversy over whether or not they are on topic for the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/assisting-with-godaddy-deletions/333768#333768).

*[Suspicious voting activity occurring when assisting with the Apple tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348911/suspicious-voting-activity-occurring-when-assisting-with-the-apple-tag-burninati)*

*[Can we remove the HTC tag from many of the Android questions, instead of deleting them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355709/can-we-remove-the-htc-tag-from-many-of-the-android-questions-instead-of-deletin)*

*[Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience)*

In the spirit of consistency and thoroughness, can we include the requirement for a community wiki for tag replacement suggestions?

If so, can we edit [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/3956566) in the FAQ to add it?

Comment: NO! That is my answer, don't touch it! ... oh wait ... it is a community wiki ... What are you expecting of answers here? A text proposal or a simple, yes or no with some arguments after which you'll edit the answer based on the consensus?

Comment: @rene sounds a plan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial idea when I wrote that answer was to use the progress answer to include guidance for anyone who wanted to chip in.

So the progress answer was merely meant as a convenient starting point, not as a cast in stone template. It should and needs to be adapted to fit the specific tag burnination at hand.

Do notice that the answer also says: *The team that takes the burnination on can be:the OP; a couple of interested commenters; a topic specific chatroom; the SOCVR room.* I'm used to letting teams organize themselves which is probably also why I left it at a generic template.

That said: I do see there are more *complex*, either due to size or overlap between major tags, burninations taken on now and those need more discussion/guidance to prevent value is lost. I would suggest to add the  following to the burnination guidance in step 4:

> Provide enough practical guidance for the users participating on the burnination either by editing the progress answer or by posting an extra [*Observations*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355967/578411) answer that can extend both action and rationale for typical questions and/or combination of tags.
>   In all cases make sure some consensus is reached, either in chat or by providing answers or comments before taking anything on.

I'm not a technical writer so feel free to take it from here. As the answer in the FAQ is community wiki I leave it at others to make the final edit.

Comment: Yep I think this is good. I guess we wait for votes. *pours coffee and sits watching screen*